# Excel Sheet not saving

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code below that saves an excel sheet with the contents of a couple of cells.  When I run the code, no error is detected.  The save as box comes up which I want and I press save as normal and it appears to save BUT this does not save or overwrite a file.

```
Sub FileSave()

Dim IntialName As String Dim fileSaveName As Variant InitialName =
Range("C2") & "Cash Sheet" fileSaveName =
Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, _
fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")

If fileSaveName <> False Then
MsgBox "Save as " & fileSaveName End If

End Sub
```

Unsure as to why this is happening.

Many Thanks

J

Comment: No where in your code you are performing actual save. You are getting the file name to save, checking if the Filename is true or false? and then code finishes. where is the save method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the save command :)

```
    Workbook.SaveAs fileSaveName
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx